# Arguments expansion in IfSubStr

Tags: macros, expansion, xstring

### EDIT: Simplified question

How can I make the following code print "Yes"?

```
\IfSubStr{\textbf{AAA}}{AAA}{Yes}{No}
```

---

### Full question

I'm playing with `xstring`'s `IfSubStr`, but I don't really understand how expansion works.

Here's a largely simplified MWE demonstrating my problem:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\correctanswer}{}
\newcommand{\mytext}[1]{
    Text :
    \noexpandarg
    \IfSubStr{#1}{\correctanswer}{
        \textbf{\boldmath #1}
    }{
        #1
    }
}
\newcommand{\mymathtext}[1]{\mytext{\ensuremath{#1}}}

\begin{document}
    \mytext{Foo} \mytext{Bar\correctanswer} \mymathtext{\frac{1}{2}} \mymathtext{\frac{1}{4}\correctanswer}
\end{document}
```

The code works as follow: first define a `\correctanswer` which expands to an empty string, and second emphasize (by typesetting in bold) text that contains this macro.

I'm using `xstring`'s `\noexpandarg` to prevent `\correctanswer` from being expanded too early, but that doesn't work when the argument text is already passed to another command, such as `\ensuremath` : **Although `Bar` is typeset in bold, `\frac{1}{4}` is not.**

How can I get `\frac{1}{4}` to be typeset in bold?

PS: I don't really understand how expansion works. I've read a number of posts on this site, but I still can't figure out a correct solution to this particular problem. I therefore haven't included the numerous unfruitful attempts that I made, hoping that someone could instead provide me with a clear explanation :)

Comment: For those wondering why I'm using such a bizarre syntax: I'm trying to build my own mutiple-choice template, and my current code has a `\choice` command chich takes four arguments, with one (or more) containing `\correctanswer`, which allows me to use the same document for the test and the correction, by switching between `\solutionstrue` and `\solutionsfalse`.

Comment: why not use the syntax `\correctanswer{\mytext{Bar}}`, defining it either as `\newcommand{\correctanswer}[1]{#1}` or `\newcommand{\correctanswer}[1]{\textbf{#1}}` depending on `\ifsolutions`? Using `xstring` here seems like an overkill.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: Salut Bruno. In my full example, I do more than making the text bold: there's a checkbox before every answer, which gets checked if \ifsolutions is true and the answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the relevant section in `xstring`'s manual, I realize that using `IfSubStr*` works perfectly =)

Comment: It does; but one has to think whether adding a `\correctanswer` tag inside the argument is really a good solution. I don't think so.

Comment: @egreg: Your solution is indeed very pretty; the only trouble that I have atm is that my real-life document has constructs like `\choices{Choice 1}{Choice 2}{Choice 3}{Choice 4}`, and the command `\choices` in turns calls `\mytext` four times, and `\mytext` adds a checkbox before every choice, and in solution mode checks the right box. I think that the ideal solution would be to pass to `\choices` a second argument (a number between 1 and 4), which would specify which answer is correct, but since I didn't know how to do that I thought I'd tag the correct answer with \correctanswer.

Answer (score 6):

Just don't use `\ensuremath`: it adds a level of grouping that makes impossible for `\IfSubStr` to find `\correctanswer`; indeed the test

```
\IfSubStr{1{2}3}{2}{true}{false}
```

returns "false". So write

```
\newcommand{\mymathtext}[1]{\mytext{$#1$}}
```

Please, note that your code adds plenty of spurious spaces:

```
\newcommand{\mytext}[1]{%
    Text :
    \noexpandarg
    \IfSubStr{#1}{\correctanswer}{%
        \textbf{\boldmath #1}%
    }{%
        #1%
    }
}
```

I would rewrite it as

```
\newcommand{\mytext}[1]{%
    Text : % be sure we want a space
    \noexpandarg
    \IfSubStr{#1}{\correctanswer}
      {\textbf{\boldmath #1}}
      {#1}%
}
```

But probably the best thing is to define a *-variant:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mytext}{\@ifstar\mytext@s\mytext@n}
\newcommand{\mytext@s}[1]{\textbf{\boldmath #1}}
\newcommand{\mytext@n}[1]{#1}
\makeatother
```

and say `\mytext{Yes}` or `\mytext*{No}` (correct answer); for math just add `$`: `\mytext{$\frac{1}{2}$}` or `\mytext*{$\frac{1}{4}$}`

This is the standard way to define a command with a *-variant; since we need to use `@` commands, the code must be enclosed between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

The command `\mytext` is defined to peek at what follows it with `\@ifstar`; if a `*` follows, we execute `\mytext@s`, otherwise `\mytext@n`, that we define next just normally: `\mytext@s{x}` does `\textbf{\boldmath x}`, while `\mytext@n{x}` does simply `x`. Indeed TeX will substitute `\mytext*` with `\mytext@s`, so it will next see the argument to pass to this command, and similarly without a `*`.

In order to arrange things with `\ifsolution`, you can say

```
\newif\ifsolution
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mytext}{\@ifstar\mytext@s\mytext@n}
\newcommand{\mytext@s}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \ifsolution\bfseries\boldmath\fi
  #1%
  \endgroup}
\newcommand{\mytext@s}[1]{#1}
\makeatletter
```

so that the `\bfseries\boldmath` commands will be issued only when `\ifsolution` is set to true.

### Simpler version

A simpler definition might be:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\newif\ifsolution

\NewDocumentCommand{\answer}{st{+}m}
  {\begingroup
   \ifsolution\IfBooleanT{#1}{\bfseries\boldmath}\fi
   \IfBooleanT{#2}{$}#3\IfBooleanT{#2}{$}%
   \endgroup}

\answer{Yes} \answer*{No}

\answer+{\frac{1}{2}} \answer*+{\frac{1}{4}}

\solutiontrue

\answer{Yes} \answer*{No}

\answer+{\frac{1}{2}} \answer*+{\frac{1}{4}}
```

You'll get

> Yes No
>   1/2 1/4
>   Yes **No**
>   1/2 **1/4**

with the fractions in math mode, of course. The presence of + implies a formula, as you can see.

### EDIT

Assuming that you have a `\answerformat` macro that formats answers, say

```
\newcommand{\answerformat}[1]{\mbox{\checkbox\qquad{#1}}\\}
```

(where `\checkbox` prints a box), you can use a syntax such as

```
\answers{Yes}*{No}+{\frac{1}{2}}+{\frac{1}{4}}
```

or even

```
\answers[3]{Yes}{No}*+{\frac{1}{2}}
```

that is, preceding the correct answer by `*` and math answers by `+`; the optional argument tells how many choices you have (default 4):

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\answer}{st{+}m}
  {\answerformat{%
     \ifsolution\IfBooleanT{#1}{\bfseries\boldmath}\fi
     \IfBooleanT{#2}{$}#3\IfBooleanT{#2}{$}}
   \ifnum\value{anscount}<\answernumber
     \stepcounter{anscount}\expandafter\answer
   \fi}
\NewDocumentCommand{\answers}{O{4}}
  {\setcounter{anscount}{1}\chardef\answernumber=#1\relax
   \answer}
\newcounter{anscount}
```

Comment: Awesome answer. Just let me some time to make sure I fully understand it: I had never heard about *-variants before :)

Comment: Probably the last version is the most flexible one (just don't ever write `\answer+*`).

Comment: Can you explain how the `@n` and `@s` notations work (or point me to a relevant resource)? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think you can also use xstring. Use the commands `exploregroup` and `noexpandarg`.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\correctanswer}{}
\newcommand{\mytext}[1]{
    Text :
    \noexpandarg
    \exploregroups
    \IfSubStr{#1}{\correctanswer}{
        \textbf{\boldmath #1}
    }{%
        #1
    }
}
\newcommand{\mymathtext}[1]{\mytext{\ensuremath{#1}}}

\begin{document}
    \mytext{Foo} \mytext{Bar\correctanswer} \mymathtext{\frac{1}{2}} \mymathtext{\frac{1}{4}\correctanswer}
\end{document}
```

[image]